# storybook not able to detect right builder for angular project

Tags: angular, components, storybook, angular-storybook

I have configured a multi-project angular workspace. Inside the angular workspace project folder, I have one project application folder `eventric`, and one library folder `storybook`.

[image]

In this multilevel angular workspace. I want to configure my storybook inside the library called `storybook`.

Here is what I did so far.

Went inside the folder storybook.

executed

```
npx storybook@latest init
```

Now the storybook cli is not able to detect the project type, and giving me the following option to select.
[image]

I am new to angular and I am not sure what to select here.

**What should I do to auto-detect the project type?**

Answer (score 0):

You should change the tsconfig.json and ng-package.json path for auto-detecting, but I suggest you create Storybook Immediate inside your main project because if you want to update any Storybook version, you will need to update the path manually instead of using the auto-upgrade command.

Eventric > (your storybook folder should be here immediately for auto-detecting)

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/next/code/frameworks/angular#setup-storybook-for-your-angular-projects you have to run `npx storybook@latest init` in your root directory. In Storybook 7 we automatically detect that you have multiple projects and a prompt will ask you in which app/lib you want to set up Storybook